# How to paste a large text in browser in HTML text area

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, clipboard

I'm trying to paste a large material on my site.

Unfortunately, if I select more then a 1000 lines or so browser doesn't react on 'paste' command. I can paste it in text editor without any trouble, though.

I tried with Firefox 3.6, Opera 11 under Ubuntu 10.04 and 10.10.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it's really text. If you copy from another browser, word processor, e-mail, then it's likely represented on the clipboard as HTML and RTF, along with "plain text".  Do a "cleanse" by pasting into Notepad, then re-copying FROM Notepad, and then see if it pastes. If it does, then the problem is with the heavy-weight formats.

The other thing that makes me wonder... when you say "paste a large material on my site", what does that mean, really?  You're pasting into a text box? What happens next, it's inserted into a database via PHP or something?  It really isn't clear what you're doing here.